# Difference between $(document).ready() and $(window).load() in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

What is the difference between

```
$(document).ready(function(){});
```

AND

```
$(window).load(function(){});
```

Comment: Did you even search for this at all before posting?

Comment: Please take some time to search for an existing post in the future before posting a new one. As you can see there are numerous possible duplicates.

Comment: Simple terms, Document fires when the document is ready or (DOM). And window `.load` fires when the window is ready. In chrome for example, you can't get correct css dimensions using jQuery methods such as `.width()` or `.height()` until the window is ready.

Comment: There is no difference, both have absolutely no effect, binding empty handler...

Comment: @Lix Stackoverflow need to make question duplicates more noticeable to posters. Probably bigger and highlighted with colors. Maybe add an arrow or two.

Comment: @NoName - You may have a point there... Also I don't remember if the duplicate suggestions looked the same 5 years ago when this post was made :)

Answer (score 1):

From the **[docs](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)**:

> Code included inside $( document ).ready() will only run once the page
>   Document Object Model (DOM) is ready for JavaScript code to execute.
>   Code included inside $( window ).load(function() { ... }) will run
>   once the entire page (images or iframes), not just the DOM, is ready.

Comment: +1 because i guess OP didn't know jQuery has some documentation publicly available ;)